# using between function in oracle

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have already searched the internet what is the logic in oracle when using a between function in string but couldn't seem to find or understand it.

For example.

```
 select 1 from dual
 where 'M9W'  between  'M9W0A0' and 'M9W9Z9'
```

Why would the above query would not return a row?

Can someone please explain?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String comparison is based on alphabetical order.  The string `M9W` is not alphabetically between `M9W0A0` and `M9W9Z9`.  Alphabetically, it comes before both.  Alphabetically, it comes before any string `M9W<<any character(s) here>>`.

Comment: select 1 from dual where 'M9W0a'  between  'M9W0A0' and 'M9W9Z9'. This query returns a value. But this select 1 from dual where 'M9W0A'  between  'M9W0A0' and 'M9W9Z9'does not. Can you please explain?

Comment: If you sort 3 strings A-z, will be M9W0A, then M9W0A0, then M9W9Z9.

Comment: @user2058738 - Same issue.  Alphabetically, `a` comes after `A`.

Comment: @user2058738 - there's a section in the manual [all about linguistic sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm)